# How to add "Order Online" link on GMB using the API

Tags: google-my-business-api

[NOTE: This may be not the right place for this question. Can you please refer me to the right place if this is not.]

I know you can login to GMB, verify the business and than add the "Order Online" link from the GMB console.

We are an agency and expanding fast so we are trying to find out a way of adding our link to all our customer's GMB pages without needing to getting verified for each of them separately but rather using the API if possible.

[image]

Anyone here has experience doing this? I looked through the API, but can not find anything like this.

Comment: And how shall this question be related to programming?

Comment: @MartinZeitler - I am looking for any API reference to this specific problem. Please also notice that on the first line, I made clear that I understand that issue and asking for the community to guide me to the right place if this is not.

Comment: Just voted to close this, because requesting off-site resource is considered off-topic... there might not even be any "API way", but these distributors would need to link these by place ID. So the links will be added, only when they offer it, not when you claim they would offer it. You'd need to get that business listed with them, then it should appear (I also have hotel bookings listed there, but only based upon the fact, that they offer booking for that place ID). It's alike merged business listings.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to influence this attribute. See this [article](https://support.google.com/business/answer/6218037?hl=en)

> In some cases, links to certain third-party booking services will appear automatically on business listings. These links cannot be edited in Google My Business.
>
> If you want to remove or fix a link in your own listing, please contact the third-party provider’s support team or a technical contact to request they remove your data from the information they are sending Google.

Comment: Hi @kmgt "links to certain third-party booking services will appear automatically on business listings"

I am looking for the answer to that "Appear Automatically" phrase to be precise